# cant get source('plot_entropy.R') to work

Tags: r

Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
cannot open file 'plot_entropy.R': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Your working directory has to be set to the exact location of the file your try to read.

Check with `getwd()` and change it accordingly with `setwd("path/to/the/file")`

Alternatively you can give the complete file path directly in `source("path/to/the/file/plot_entropy.R")`.